# CommandParameter is Nothing from ListView command binding

Tags: wpf, listview, commandbinding, commandparameter

I am not succeeding in sending CommandParameter from ListView item. My code is below.

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}"                        
     <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
               <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myList}" >
                                      <Button.Content>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeValue}" />
                                            </StackPanel>      
                                      </Button.Content>
                                 </Button>
                           </DataTemplate>   
                      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
          </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

When the item on ListView is clicked, the command is called okay, but the CommandParameter shows Nothing. 
What's the problem here?

ViewModel command is here:

```
Public ReadOnly Property MyData As List(Of myObject)
    Get
        Return _myObjectrepo.GetAll()
    End Get 
End Property

Public Property MyCommand As ICommand
    Get
        If _myCommand Is Nothing Then
            _myCommand = New RelayCommandWithParameter(Of myObject)(AddressOf Navigate)
        End If
        Return _myCommand 
    End Get
    Set(value As ICommand)
        _myCommand = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _myCommand As ICommand
```

...and the procedure where I try to use the CommandParameter

```
Private Sub Navigate(m As myObject)
    If m IsNot Nothing Then

    End If
End Sub
```

...but the m is Nothing in the above procedure.

Comment: `{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=myList}` should do the trick

Comment: Can you post the command code? Could be that the casting is problematic

Comment: Assuming `MyData` is a collection of `X`, make sure the command definition in your viewModel gets `X` as parameter

Comment: Added ViewModel code the my initial post...

Comment: Do you have any binding errors in the output window of Visual Studio?

Comment: No I don't have any binding errors. I am wondering if CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myList}" is the right way to do it?

Comment: Try CommandParameter="{Binding}" for the clicked on item

Comment: @ZSH-Correct..!! It will work for CommandParameter="{Binding}"

Comment: Great, with CommandParameter="{Binding}" it is working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copied the answer from comments:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```